How to correct box movement
I am trying to develop a 3D Sokoban game in Unity, I made the player movement and colliders using raycasting so it doesn't goes through obstacles. I have already made the player push the box as well, however, the box is not colliding with obstacles as player does, I don't know how to fix it. Also, I am no expert in unity or general programming, this is for a school project
I leave the scripts as well so you can take a look, thank you in advance:
The code is supposedly working without colliders, there's only the option for the box marked, the "Is trigger" checkmark and raycasting as I need it to be a grid based movement, both the box and the player must only be able to move in 4 directions, I have tried to create a condition in which the raycasting seeks for an obstacle excluding the player and if the ray hits it, deny the movement in that direction
PlayerMovement:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 0.25f;
    [SerializeField] float rayLength = 1.4f;

    Vector3 targetPosition;
    bool moving;

    void Update()
    {
        if (moving)
        {
            transform.position += (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Check if the player has reached the target position
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) < 0.05f)
            {
                transform.position = targetPosition;
                moving = false;
            }

            return;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            Move(Vector3.forward);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            Move(Vector3.back);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Move(Vector3.left);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Move(Vector3.right);
        }
    }

    void Move(Vector3 direction)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, direction, out hit, rayLength) || hit.collider.CompareTag("Box"))
        {
            targetPosition = transform.position + direction;
            moving = true;
        }
    }
}

BoxMovement:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoxMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 0.25f;
    [SerializeField] float maxRayLength = 2.0f;

    Vector3 targetPosition;
    Vector3 startPosition;
    bool moving;

    void Update()
    {
        if (moving)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(startPosition, transform.position) > 1f)
            {
                transform.position = targetPosition;
                moving = false;
                return;
            }
            transform.position += (targetPosition - startPosition) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            return;
        }

        // Check for player input to move the box
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (!RaycastDirection(Vector3.forward))
                return;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            if (!RaycastDirection(Vector3.back))
                return;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if (!RaycastDirection(Vector3.left))
                return;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            if (!RaycastDirection(Vector3.right))
                return;
        }
    }

    bool RaycastDirection(Vector3 playerMovement)
    {
        Vector3 direction = -playerMovement; // Invert direction to move forward
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, direction, out hit, Mathf.Min(maxRayLength, maxRayLength)))
        {
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                // Move in the direction of the player's movement
                targetPosition = transform.position + playerMovement;
                startPosition = transform.position;
                moving = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


you should do this different: handle input only on the player, not on the box. If the player is standing right next to a box then the player controls the movement of the box instead. Further the player also can perform a nested raycast check whether behind the box is another box or even a wall/obstacle ... They player should be the one central place handling interactions and influencing the rest of the scene
